Why does my macos configuration block IPv4-mapped IPv6 UDP responses?
I am currently debugging a DNS problem with an application on my mac. I am hoping somebody can point me in the correct direction for further debugging. My problem is that DNS requests made over a IPv6 socket to an IPv4 address can be sent, but the response never reaches my program. Originally this occurred using the netty dns resolver in a java program, but I could reproduce it in a simple C program:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int sock,bytes_recv,sin_size;
    struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr6;
    // DNS Packet for www.googleapis.com
    char send_data[] = {60, 15, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 119, 119, 119, 10, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 97, 112, 105, 115, 3, 99, 111, 109, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 41, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    char recv_data[1024];

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct in6_addr host6_addr;
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:808:808", &host6_addr) != 1) {
        perror("inet_pton");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_addr6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_addr6.sin6_port = htons(53);
    server_addr6.sin6_addr = host6_addr;

    sendto(sock, send_data, 48, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr6, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));

    int sin6_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);
    bytes_recv = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr6, &sin6_size);
    printf("Received:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_recv; i ++) {
        printf(" %02x", recv_data[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

This tries to make a DNS request to 8.8.8.8 using IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses. The problem is the recvfrom call never returns.
I can see the request and the response using tcpdump -fl -i utun3 udp | grep -F '8.8.8.8':
14:28:10.436223 IP 10.255.226.30.60077 > 8.8.8.8.domain: 15375+ [1au] A? www.googleapis.com. (48)
14:28:10.453931 IP 8.8.8.8.domain > 10.255.226.30.60077: 15375 16/0/1 A 172.217.175.234, A 172.217.175.42, A 172.217.161.42, A 216.58.220.138, A 142.250.196.106, A 142.250.196.138, A 172.217.175.74, A 216.58.220.106, A 142.250.207.10, A 142.251.222.10, A 142.251.42.138, A 142.251.42.170, A 142.251.42.202, A 142.251.222.42, A 172.217.26.234, A 172.217.161.74 (303)

As you can guess from the dump I am required to use a VPN and route all the traffic through there. I am not sure this is the cause though, as requests to my local router(192.168.2.1) not sent through the VPN fail in the same way. IPv6 is disabled by the way, but enabling it does not change the situation:
$ networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi                                                                                                                                                             
DHCP Configuration
IP address: 192.168.2.144
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.2.1
Client ID: 
IPv6: Off
Wi-Fi ID: 3c:06:30:38:77:e2

I tried querying the IPV6_V6ONLY option with getsockopt. It returns 0 so is disabled.
The same code with IPv4 sockets work and also the IPv6 code on my other mac works. Is there some system configuration that I am missing? I am happy to provide further debugging information if required.

See the IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry where it explains that IPv4-mapped Addresses cannot be used as Source or Destination addresses, are not Forwardable nor Globally Reachable, and they are reserved by IPv6 itself.

Thank you for your comment! It does not seems like they get sent out as packets ever. I have not looked into the kernel code myself, but it seems like they get converted pretty early on to the equivalent IPv4 address and then the IPv4 stack is used. If I interpret RFC4038 correctly this should be a valid use case of the addresses.

Also the code is working on one of my macs, but not the other. I don't think it is a problem with the code in general.
